# How do i generate a histogram for a given probability distribution (for functional testing a server)?

Tags: python, statistics, simulation, stress-testing

I am trying to automate functional testing of a server using a realistic frequency distribution of requests. (sort of load testing, sort of simulation)

I've chosen the [Weibull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) distribution as it "sort of" matches the distribution I've observed (ramps up quickly, drops off quickly but not instantly)

I use this distribution to generate the number of requests that should be sent each day between a given start and end date

I've hacked together an algorithm in Python that sort of works but it feels kludgy:

```
how_many_days = (end_date - start_date).days
freqs = defaultdict(int)
for x in xrange(how_many_responses):
    freqs[int(how_many_days * weibullvariate(0.5, 2))] += 1
timeline = []
day = start_date
for i,freq in sorted(freqs.iteritems()):
    timeline.append((day, freq))
    day += timedelta(days=1)
return timeline
```

What better ways are there to do this?

Comment: This algorithm always returns the expected number of responses, but it usually won't fit them exactly between the start and end dates, I'm not sure this is possible unless I manually mess with the frequencies?

Comment: They're not guaranteed to be fitted between the start and end dates because you're using a probability distribution with infinite support. As long as you use the random number returned from the distribution unchanged as a key, you're going to have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quick and probably not that accurate, but if you calculate the PDF yourself, then at least you make it easier to lay several smaller/larger ones on a single timeline. `dev` is the std deviation in the Guassian noise, which controls the roughness. Note that this is *not* the 'right' way to generate what you want, but it's easy.

```
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from random import gauss

how_many_responses = 1000
start_date = date(2008, 5, 1)
end_date = date(2008, 6, 1)
num_days = (end_date - start_date).days + 1
timeline = [start_date + timedelta(i) for i in xrange(num_days)]

def weibull(x, k, l):
    return (k / l) * (x / l)**(k-1) * math.e**(-(x/l)**k)

dev = 0.1
samples = [i * 1.25/(num_days-1) for i in range(num_days)]
probs = [weibull(i, 2, 0.5) for i in samples]
noise = [gauss(0, dev) for i in samples]
simdata = [max(0., e + n) for (e, n) in zip(probs, noise)]
events = [int(p * (how_many_responses / sum(probs))) for p in simdata]

histogram = zip(timeline, events)

print '\n'.join((d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') + "*" * c) for d,c in histogram)
```

Comment: Great the distribution looks much better the one generated via simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try [The Grinder 3](http://grinder.sourceforge.net) to load test your server, it comes with all this and more prebuilt, and it supports python as a scripting language

Comment: Well unfortunately, this is function is going to be used in some functional tests as well so I'd love to keep it all in family as much as possible.  Maybe simulation is a better description than load testing

Answer (score 1):

Slightly longer but probably more readable rework of your last four lines:

```
samples = [0 for i in xrange(how_many_days + 1)]
for s in xrange(how_many_responses):
    samples[min(int(how_many_days * weibullvariate(0.5, 2)), how_many_days)] += 1
histogram = zip(timeline, samples)
print '\n'.join((d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') + "*" * c) for d,c in histogram)
```

This always drops the samples within the date range, but you get a corresponding bump at the end of the timeline from all of the samples that are above the [0, 1] range.

Comment: Nice, i like it.  I always try to stuff things in iterators, but this is definitely easier to read :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the number of requests as a fixed value, why not use a scaling factor instead? At the moment, you're treating requests as a limited quantity, and randomising the days on which those requests fall. It would seem more reasonable to treat your requests-per-day as independent.

```
from datetime import *
from random import *

timeline = []
scaling = 10
start_date = date(2008, 5, 1)
end_date = date(2008, 6, 1)

num_days = (end_date - start_date).days + 1
days = [start_date + timedelta(i) for i in range(num_days)]
requests = [int(scaling * weibullvariate(0.5, 2)) for i in range(num_days)]
timeline = zip(days, requests)
timeline
```

Comment: This function doesn't seem to produce the shape I'm looking for. If you check the wikipedia article, I chose the red curve that ramps up fast and then trails off over time as seems to model page views, initially high but then people lose interest in the new content over time.

Comment: In fact the whole point (from my perspective :-) is that the number of requests depends on the day. I'm not just trying to model random loads across a period of time.

Comment: Okay, but what you're doing now is just approximating the distribution. Why not use the distribution itself, or the distribution plus some noise?

As it stands, you're modelling a history-dependent process without using any history.

Comment: Well that's pretty much my question, how do I generate the distribution + noise, preferably using stdlib functions?  I could write my own PDF function and evaluate + perturb at each point...but that seems harder than writing this approximation.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the code above to be shorter (but maybe it's too obfuscated now?)

```
timeline = (start_date + timedelta(days=days) for days in count(0))
how_many_days = (end_date - start_date).days
pick_a_day = lambda _:int(how_many_days * weibullvariate(0.5, 2))
days = sorted(imap(pick_a_day, xrange(how_many_responses)))
histogram = zip(timeline, (len(list(responses)) for day, responses in groupby(days)))
print '\n'.join((d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') + "*" * c) for d,c in histogram)
```

Comment: These are the imports for the function above:    
    from datetime import datetime,timedelta
    from random import weibullvariate
    from itertools import imap,count,groupby
    how_many_responses = 100
    start_date = date(2008, 5, 1)
    end_date = date(2008, 6, 1)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [Rpy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/), which puts all of the power of R (including lots of tools for distributions), easily into Python.